# Replace @Value property within @Configuration during Spring Boot test

Tags: testing, spring-boot

## Scenario

I've got a Spring Boot application with a `@Configuration` annotated Spring configuration class which contains some `@Value` annotated fields. For testing I want to replace these field values with custom test values.

Unfortunately these test values cannot be overridden using a simple properties file, (String) constants or similar, instead I **must** use some custom written property resolving Java class (e.g. `TargetProperties.getProperty("some.username")`).

The problem I have is that when I add a custom `PropertySource` to the `ConfigurableEnvironment` within my test configuration, it's already too late because this `PropertySource` will be added **after** the e.g. `RestTemplate` has been created.

## Question

How can I override `@Value` annotated fields *within* a `@Configuration` class with properties obtained *programmatically* via custom Java code *before* anything else gets initialized?

## Code

### Production Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration {

    @Value("${some.username}")
    private String someUsername;

    @Value("${some.password}")
    private String somePassword;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate someRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(
            new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(someUsername, somePassword));

        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

### Test Configuration Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class SomeTest {

    @SpringBootConfiguration
    @Import({MySpringBootApp.class, SomeConfiguration.class})
    static class TestConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        private ConfigurableEnvironment configurableEnvironment;

        // This doesn't work:

        @Bean
        @Lazy(false)
        // I also tried a @PostConstruct method
        public TargetPropertiesPropertySource targetPropertiesPropertySource() {
            TargetPropertiesPropertySource customPropertySource =
                new TargetPropertiesPropertySource();
            configurableEnvironment.getPropertySources().addFirst(customPropertySource);
            return customPropertySource;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use constructor injection in production cases, which allows it to set the configuration manually:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration {

    private final String someUsername;
    private final String somePassword;

    @Autowired
    public SomeConfiguration(@Value("${some.username}") String someUsername,
       @Value("${some.password}") String somePassword) {
       this.someUsername = someUsername;
       this.somePassword = somePassword;
    }
...
)
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class SomeTest {

    private SomeConfiguration config;

    @Before
    public init() {
      config = new SomeConfiguration("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can override properties directly in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation using the `properties` parameter:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"some.username=user", "some.password=pwd"},
                webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
```

Comment: This is correct for common/most cases, but my case is different in the way that I *must* retrieve these values *programmatically*

Answer (score 11):

You can use [**`@TestPropertySource`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html)

```
@TestPropertySource(
    properties = {
        "some.username=validate",
        "some.password=false"
    }
)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ApplicationTest {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is correct for common/most cases, but my case is different in the way that I *must* retrieve these values *programmatically*