# Does spring hava method to get field by @Value string literial?

Tags: java, spring

```
@Value("${properties.name:Tom}")
String name;
@Value("${properties.email}")
String email;
```

I want to get Filed by the annotation's value.
`getField("properties.name")`  returns the String field name,not the value "tom".
Does spring hava method like this?

Comment: What do you mean by `the String field name` ?

Comment: Didn't get it. Do you want `properties.name` (which is key in your .property file) instead of it's associated value (which is `Tom`)?

Comment: why do you have Tom in that value annotation?

Comment: refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396268/8096208). interesting way...

Comment: means java.lang.reflect.Field  or  something  have same use @NattyRoots

Comment: @Razib  m.antkowicz 's answer is mainly what I want

Comment: you should look at loading yml as `Map` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml

Comment: @Stultuske its a default value.I write this to remind that Spring has a series of rule to set the value, not just string compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using reflection, because `Value` has RetentionPolicy `RUNTIME`

```
Field field = Stream.of(YourClass.class.getFields())
    .filter(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(Value.class))
    .filter(field -> field.getAnnotation(Value.class).value().contains("properties.name")) // or compare to whole expression, or use startsWith, or regex... Also think about NPE check
    .findFirst()
    .orElse( /* HANDLE FIELD NOT PRESENT */);
```

Comment: but the @Value's value is "${properties.name:Tom}"  not  "properties.name".if i write this code myself,its hard to compatible with Spring.So i am looking for a method offer by Spring

Comment: Yeah I see I updated answer. Spring itself has nothing like this - I'm pretty sure. Even if it provides some reflection helpers it's still about reflection not the Spring mechanism